# How do I detect spam from among published comments?

Tags: comments, advertising

My spam prevention modules had to be disabled while I was fixing a problem. Meanwhile, I was attacked by numerous spam bots and now have thousands of published spam comments on my site.

Is there a way to detect these comments and unpublish and/or delete them?

I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

I use a view, that shows me 200 comments at once with their body. So by quickly looking at the list of the comments, I can see which are span and checkmark them to delete.

You can copy this view from the gist here: https://gist.github.com/timonweb/5990901

Make sure you have Views Bulk Operations (https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module installed, then import the view from the gist and go to: http://yoursite.com/admin/content/comment/moderate.

Comment: I was hoping for an automated method that could do the same for me. I have way too many spam comments to go through them by the hundreds or thousands. Plus performing a delete action on too many of them in one go causes the server to crash on a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Automated solutions are part of services such as akismet and mollom, people build businesses on these solutions, so I don't think you can find something working out of the box. Try this class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4236-PHP-Detect-spam-in-text-using-Bayesian-techniques.html, uses Bayesian techniques to detect spam text messages. You could write a simple module that goes through all your comments and checks them with this algorytm.

Comment: I guess I will have to create my own solution. Thanks!